# Python: PHP fatal Error Class not found when php script called from python script

Tags: php, python

I am trying to call a php script from python script using `subprocess`:

```
cmd1 = 'php -f ' + path + '/src/MarketplaceWebService/Samples/ReviseItem.php %s %s' % (sku,qty)
print cmd1
args1 = shlex.split(cmd1)
p=subprocess.Popen(args1)
p.wait()
```

But i am getting the followwing error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MarketplaceWebService_Client' not found in
>   /home/nish/stuff/repos/new/voylla_staging_changes/voylla_scripts/amazon/src/MarketplaceWebService/Samples/ReviseItem.php
>   on line 70

When I run the same php script via command line using `php -f ReviseItem.php`, it works fine without any errors. How can i fix this error.

Comment: What happens when you run the **exact same command line** you have in your python script (with the path) from another directory (say /tmp for example) ?

Comment: @Calimero : I'm getting the error again. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `include()` or `require()`  calls in your php scripts are using relative file paths, which are themselves relatives to the directory you actually are in when you run the command.

You can assert this with a `echo getcwd();` call at the beginning of your php script, for example.

So, you have to either modify your python code to **cd** to the right dir prior to running the command (easier), or modify your php scripts to use absolute paths for inclusion (not the best way to go since your scripts would be tied to a specific directory on the system).